# Sending a message before the FlutterEngine has been run when using FlutterStreamHandler

Tags: flutter

I'm using [`flutter_live_activities`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_live_activities) to add support for Live Activities on my app. Recently I noticed some occurences of an inconsistency exception:

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException
Sending a message before the FlutterEngine has been run.
```

Making further investigation, I realized that this exception is being thrown from a listener of `flutter_live_activities` that is raised when the main Flutter app is in the background. This listener calls a `FlutterEventSink` stream created using `FlutterEventSink` protocol. When trying to add to this stream, the app crashes with the exception above. Here's the call stack the reproduces the issue:

- App goes to the background
- Listener is called [here](https://github.com/istornz/flutter_live_activities/blob/581933050e1f3bb081ca5dadd44f5e960be9f363/ios/Classes/SwiftLiveActivitiesPlugin.swift#L354C1-L354C16)
- The exception is thrown

It seems that the stream must be disposed somehow, but the plugin seems to be correctly implementing the streams disposal [here](https://github.com/istornz/flutter_live_activities/blob/main/ios/Classes/SwiftLiveActivitiesPlugin.swift#L25-L46):

```swift
public func onListen(withArguments arguments: Any?, eventSink events: @escaping FlutterEventSink) -> FlutterError? {
    if let args = arguments as? String{
      if (args == "urlSchemeStream") {
        urlSchemeSink = events
      } else if (args == "activityUpdateStream") {
        activityEventSink = events
      }
    }
    
    return nil
  }
  
  public func onCancel(withArguments arguments: Any?) -> FlutterError? {
    if let args = arguments as? String{
      if (args == "urlSchemeStream") {
        urlSchemeSink = nil
      } else if (args == "activityUpdateStream") {
        activityEventSink = nil
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
```

In this case, what should be disposed and it's not being disposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by disposing the Flutter sinks and listeners in the plugin iOS side when the engine gets destroyed.

Refer to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135613 for a more in-depth explanation and other useful links that explains this issue in details.